# What is the most common name for staging/pre-production/prod-like deployment environment?

Tags: deployment, naming-conventions, naming, conventions

We use several different names for the "staging/pre-production/prod-like" deployment environment in our organization. This environment is very close to production and we do final tests there before deploying a new version to production.
We would like to reduce this naming entropy and use one of the most common name. We are interested in the opinion of the community on this issue.